# c++ How to create an instance of derived class template

Tags: c++, templates

I have `base` class and a bunch of derived classes (only one here for simplicity). I also have `holder` class with one of derived classes as a template argument. I want `holder` object to create an instance of derived class. Here is the code:

```
class base {
protected:
    int value;
public:
    base() : value (0) { }
    base(int value) : value(value) { }
};

class derived : public base { };

template <class T>
class holder {
public:
    holder(T) {}
    T create(int value) {
        return T(value);
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    holder<base*> h(&derived());
    derived* d = h.create(1); // error here
}
```

I get an error `error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'base *' to 'derived *'`. I guess that's because type of variable is `holder<base*>`, so `create` method is called with `base` as template argument. But how do I cast it properly if I have a lot of derived classes?

UPD.
I changed `holder::create` method so it uses `std::remove_pointer` but I still get the same compile error.

```
T create(int value) {
    return new (std::remove_pointer<T>::type)(value);
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that you are creating a `base*` with an `int` ? Does your code compile ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Didn't the compiler also issue an error about taking an address of a temporary?

Comment: Can the holder hold derived type rather than base type?

Comment: @SlardarZhang I also need to store a list of holder's, each may hold different subclasses of base (I should have mentioned it in post). So (as far as I understand c++) , no - it can only be holder<base*>

Comment: @perencia I see now, but don't understand what can I do with it.

Comment: @LogicStuff Basically, I need an object that can store class type and instantiate this class when needed. So that I can create it like `holder<derived> holder` and later do `holder.create(int)` to get an instance of derived class initiated with `int`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i get type from pointer in a template?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218813/how-do-i-get-type-from-pointer-in-a-template)

Comment: Your problem is that `T` is pointer and It looks like you want to create temporary from type to which pointer is pointing, you'll have to use `remove_pointer<T>`.

Comment: @PcAF I updated holder::create method, but the problem isn't gone.

Comment: Oh, that was first problem, second problem is that you are trying to assign `base*` to `derived*`. That can be done with casts, however this would be safe only if `base*` was really pointing to `derived` object. It's not safe to repoint `derived*` to object of type `base`.

Comment: And your updated `holder::create` is still bad. Return type is still `T`, it should be `remove_pointer<T>::type create(int value)` and since `remove_pointer<T>::type` is *dependent type*, you should use `typename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can let holder holds derived type rather than base type, and use `boost::any` or `std::any` (c++ 17) to store all the holders.

```
#include "iostream"
#include "boost/any.hpp"
#include "vector"

class base {
protected:
    int value;
public:
    base() : value (0) { }
    base(int value) : value(value) { }
};

class derived1 : public base {
public:
    derived1(int value) : base(value) {};
};
class derived2 : public base {
public:
    derived2(int value) : base(value) {};
};

template <class T>
class holder {
public:
    holder() {}
    T* create(int value) {
        return new T(value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<boost::any> list;
    holder<derived1> h1;
    holder<derived2> h2;
    list.push_back(h1);
    list.push_back(h2);
    derived1* pd1 = boost::any_cast<holder<derived1>>(list[0]).create(1);
    derived2* pd2 = boost::any_cast<holder<derived2>>(list[1]).create(2);
}
```

Comment: That seams to do what I need. Do you by any chance know is there `any` class for Qt?

Comment: I didn't heard that.@VladShevchenko