# what does the < > beside the struct do?

Tags: c++

Ok the following code is copied from another stackoverflow question
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218813/how-do-i-get-type-from-pointer-in-a-template)

```
template<typename T>
struct remove_pointer
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename T>
struct remove_pointer<T*>
{
    typedef typename remove_pointer<T>::type type;
};
```

While I do understand that this is a recursive definition in template, what puzzled me are the lines

```
template<typename T>
struct remove_pointer<T*>
```

does that mean **remove_pointer** will result in **T=int***? Why wouldn't T=int**? explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a specialization for pointer types. Specializations may also have template parameters. So this template's `type` is just `T` in the general case but, if `T` is a pointer type, then its `type` is `T` with the pointer removed. Maybe it is more clear when giving the parameter a different name:

```
template<typename T>
struct remove_pointer
{
    typedef T type;
};

template<typename S>
struct remove_pointer<S*>       // specialization for T = S*
{
    typedef typename remove_pointer<S>::type type;
};
```

i.e. in the general case `type` is just `T`, but if `T` is a pointer, then the template is instantiated for `S`, where `T == S*`.

PS: I think the special thing about this example is that the specialization introduces a new template parameter. A "normal" specialization would look like this:

```
template<>
struct remove_pointer<int*>   // specialization for T = int*
{
    typedef typename remove_pointer<int>::type type;
};
```

However, this isnt very useful, as we want it to work for any type. The solution is to introduce an additional template parameter on the specialization (`S`). Afaik this additional parameter has to be deducible from the parameters to the original template, in this case `S` can be deduced, because `S` is just `T` without the pointer.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. But before I accept the answer, I just wanna make sure that I actually understood what you said there, remove_pointer<A> will invoke the function at the top while remove_pointer<A*> will invoke the function at the bottom right? And the pointer specialization has to be used together with template? or it works in general? is there any online reference to this?

Comment: Yes you are right. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwrXHznaYLA) is a video that explains in detail type deduction for templates. He also mentions at some point the case where a specialization introduces an additional template parameter. I will also edit the answer, trying to make it a bit more clear